# ВИВЕСТИ ИЗОБРАЖЕНИЕ В DIV ПРИ НАЖАТИЕ на КНОПКИ

Tags: javascript, html, css

Вот кнопки, подскажите пж новичку как это правильно сделать

```
<div class="row">
<div class="column" onclick="openTab('b1');" style="background:rgb(171, 74, 74)">​Кровоносна система</div>
<div class="column" onclick="openTab('b2');" style="background:rgb(45, 45, 112);">​Нервова система</div>
<div class="column" onclick="openTab('b3');" style="background:rgba(63, 138, 163, 0.988);">​​Дихальна система</div>
<div class="column" onclick="openTab('b4');" style="background:rgb(152, 152, 40);">​Травна система.</div>
<div class="column" onclick="openTab('b5');" style="background:rgb(226, 191, 139);">​Кісткова система</div>
<div class="column" onclick="openTab('b6');" style="background:#c1427dc8;">​М'язова система</div>
</div>
```

Это главный div куда нужно выводит

```
<div  class="titl-img">
    <img src="images/im_site_2.png" style="width:50%">
</div>
```

Comment: У вас есть функция на каждый див, вот только не добавили саму функцию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример моего решения

```js
let box = document.getElementById('img-box')

function addImage(src){
  box.innerHTML = `
  <img src="${src}"/>
  ` 
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="btn-box" class="btn-box">
    
    <button onClick="addImage('https://www.cdssolution.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/logo-3.png')">one image</button>

  </div>
  <div id="img-box" class="conteiner"></div>
</body>
```

Можно добавлять url картинок которые хочешь увидеть после нажатия на кнопку

Comment: Огромное спасибо за подсказку, еще один вопрос как в одно onclick="openTab('b3')" добавить ссылку на изображение ?

Comment: Все разобрался, просто от души